# MongoDB.service failed with result exit-code

Tags: mongodb, bdd

I can't start mongoDB with the command "sudo systemctl start mongod".

I'm getting the following message :

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-02-19 22:39:00 CET; 2s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 29368 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
 Main PID: 29368 (code=exited, status=14)

Feb 19 22:39:00 pop-os systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Feb 19 22:39:00 pop-os systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Feb 19 22:39:00 pop-os systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I've already reinstalled mongodb and I having the same problem.
I don't know where the error came from if you can help me. 
Thank you.

Comment: Its always good practice is to check the logs first and find out the actual cause. Here is the log location `/var/log/mongodb/`

Answer (score 225):

Just do those two commands for temporary solution:

```sh
sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo service mongod start
```

For details:

*That shall be fault due to user permissions in .sock file*, You may have to change the owner to monogdb user.

```sh
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

For more details visit [Documentation for installation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-community/)

Comment: In case, you are getting a permission error after running chown commands, then after running each command, run "sudo !!" after each command.

Comment: Best solution, work on Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: It worked great for me on Ubuntu 22.04. Thank you very much.

Comment: it worked great for me on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.

Answer (score 37):

I had the same problem in Manjaro and these commands solved it:

```
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problem, so I tried changing the permissions and some other commands I found online that messed up my MongoDB installation. Following are the commands that I tried from online and screwed up my installation:

`$ sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`

`$ sudo systemctl status mongod`

`$ sudo systemctl start mongodb`

`$ sudo systemctl unmask mongodb`

After that, I reinstall mongodb by using following commands, which solved the issue:

`$ sudo service mongod stop`

`$ sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*`

`$ sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb`

`$ sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb`

`$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

Now start the mongodb and check the status using following commands:

`$ sudo systemctl start mongod`

`$ sudo systemctl status mongod`

Comment: Great!. This solves the problem but it removes old databases as well and everytime if we face problem for exit code , this might not work. But this time it worked

Comment: Don't forget the quotes around `sudo apt-get purge 'mongodb-org*'`

Comment: This worked for me, I also had to remove some leftovers:  `sudo rm /usr/bin/mongo*` which were conflicting from an earlier install.

Comment: Awesome! It's working for me.

Answer (score 30):

This worked for me and I don't reinstall MongoDB. I have created manually

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mongodb
sudo mkdir /var/log/mongodb
```

and changed owner for both

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
```

Comment: Every other solution didn't work, except for  this. I'm running Elementary OS

Comment: This work, thank you!

Comment: Thank you it worked. I tried everything, changing permission, reinstalling, creating and changing /data/db permissions and a lot of other things, none worked except for this

Comment: Out of curiosity, what bug does this solution fix? It seems like this shouldn't be necessary but it worked for me

Answer (score 13):

These two commands solve the problem for me(Linux Mint 20.2).

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Comment: This worked for ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This worked for me too on ubuntu 20.04...but WHY did this work @Mr.Kabir?

Comment: i can confirm that works in ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This error happend to me because of the ownship of the .sock file
just try these two command

```
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

now restart the mongo server-

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

now you can check the status of mongo server with the following command -

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

Answer (score 7):

This will worked for you and  don't reinstall MongoDB.

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mongodb
sudo mkdir /var/log/mongodb
```

then run these commands

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
```

start `mongod` service

```
sudo service mongod start
```

`mongod.service` will be `active`

```
sudo service mongod status
```

Answer (score 6):

for me, this works

```
sudo systemctl stop mongod
sudo mongod --repair --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Comment: Thanks to @[https://stackoverflow.com/users/811240/mike](Mike), I was reminded of reading logs. For this answer, the situation is that: `Failed to unlink socket file`, "Operation not permitted"`.

Answer (score 2):

It's weird that none of the other answers here mention to look in the log files. This should always be the first thing you do. On Ubuntu, this is located at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`.

In my case, I was getting messages like the following:

```json
{
   "t":{
      "$date":"2022-12-03T17:19:25.117+00:00"
   },
   "s":"F",
   "c":"CONTROL",
   "id":20574,
   "ctx":"main",
   "msg":"Error during global initialization",
   "attr":{
      "error":{
         "code":140,
         "codeName":"InvalidSSLConfiguration",
         "errmsg":"ssl client initialization problem for certificate: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem :: caused by :: The provided SSL certificate is expired or not yet valid. notBefore 2022-08-22T21:15:57.000+00:00, notAfter 2022-11-20T21:15:56.000+00:00"
      }
   }
}
```

So, the solution was to update the SSL certificate, which had expired.

If you are using Let's Encrypt, here's a `--post-hook` script to do this automatically (change example.com to your domain):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/{fullchain.pem,privkey.pem} | tee /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem 
chown mongodb:mongodb /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
chmod 600 /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
```

If the certificate already exists, you can also add this under `[renewalparams]` of `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com.conf`

```
post_hook = /root/path/to/script.sh
```

Or you can just do a one-liner instead of linking to an external script:

```
post_hook = cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem | sudo tee /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem && chown mongodb:mongodb /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem && chmod 600 /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
```

Comment: This answer should be bumped up. In my case, after looking at the log, I saw that the error was the TCP port was in use by something else. I then ran "sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN" to figure out who was the culprit (for me it was mongo running in a docker container).

Answer (score 2):

Use this command:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib//mongodb
```

then this command:

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

I was initially getting the following error when starting the Mongo Shell with (mongosh)

```
Connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.10.6
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Then I  used the code shared at the highest value in this thread and it fixed the connection:

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo service mongod start
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem, after checking the logs

#### my version

LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

```
cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

Solved the problem using this

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

In this case MongoDB running the process again and again

### The fix

To fix this just restart your machine or kill the process using the terminal:

```
ps -eaf | grep "mongod"
sudo kill <Process ID>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensuring that the MongoDB service has the necessary permissions to access and write to the MongoDB data directory.

Change the ownership of the MongoDB data directory to the mongodb user and group:

```bash
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
```

Set the appropriate permissions for the MongoDB data directory:

```bash
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mongodb
```

Restart the MongoDB service:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

Check the status of the MongoDB service to ensure it's running without errors:

```bash
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

Answer (score 1):

**For mongodb 7.0: Data loss warning**

`sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*`

`sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb`

`sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

`sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb`

`sudo systemctl start mongod`

Comment: Use a code block (triple backticks) instead of a sequence of inline code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

These 3 steps solved my problem:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --journal

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on AWS EC2 ubuntu server.
I eventually found out that this was due to lack of available space on the disk.
I ran `df -h` to determine which partition is full, and compared it to my volume on AWS console ([this guide](https://medium.com/@wlarch/no-space-left-on-device-on-my-ec2-aws-instance-cfbd69fba37a) helped).

I increased the available storage on the AWS volume, ran `sudo reboot now`  and the issue was fixed

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the network. I have changed the static IP but forgot to change the  IP in mongod.conf. It started working once i change the IP in monogd.conf.
Here is how I changed the IP

## the fix

1. go to etc/mongod.conf
2. connecting with real IP

## network interfaces

net:
port: 27017
bindIp: 127.0.0.1,xxx.xxx.xxx.xx