# Couldn't Start Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-04-20 13:32:29 IST; 6min ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 27917 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
 Main PID: 27917 (code=exited, status=14)

Apr 20 13:32:29 manojkumar systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Apr 20 13:32:29 manojkumar systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Apr 20 13:32:29 manojkumar systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Good practice is to check the logs first and find out the actual cause. Here is the log location  `/var/log/mongodb/`

Comment: You will find the answer here [on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65483737/10529914)

Answer (score 26):

It looks like mongo db fails to startup, usually it can be because the lack of permissions on mongodb's internal folders.

Try to check/set:

```
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

I've found the thread that talks about [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823288/mongodb-loads-but-breaks-returning-status-14)

Comment: your suggestion worked perfectly. I had initially installed mongodb on WSL/Debian11 over 5 weeks ago and just now getting to use it.  During that install, I had forgot to change the user/group.

Answer (score 1):

To whoever comes here with the same problem of *not able to start mongodb* with the command (sudo systemctl status mongod) after successful installation:

I had to set ulimit -n 64000 to get it to work. This is actually mentioned in the installation docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) which I had ignored initially.