# MongoDB Error: couldn't connect to server in linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, server, linux-mint

When I type 'mongo' in terminal to run the mongo server. it doesn't run. It shows me the eroor : couldn't connect to server. exception: connection failed.

Then I tried to restart mongodb server by

```
$ sudo systemctl start mongod 
$ sudo systemctl status mongod
```

When I run the status command, I see it is showing

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor prese
Active: failed (Result: exit-code)
```

N.B - I am running linux mint 20.1. And I have read all the answer and tried. But nothing worked for me.

Oh, I followed [this guide](https://www.tecmint.com/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) to install, uninstall and reinstalling MongoDB. But still it is not working for me.

Comment: can you share more detail about the error? @Moshiur Rahman Rony

Comment: Also can you share the mongo logs located in `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`

Comment: [errorr screenshot](https://imgur.com/khOrP2a.png) @rohanraj

Comment: `thor@ThorPc:~$ /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

bash: /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log: No such file or directory
` @rohanraj

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lack of permissions for MongoDB's internal folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317921/couldnt-start-mongo-db?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: I have tried this.. But it doesn't work for me ..