# mongosh: command not found and bash: /usr/bin/mongo: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

I'm a new linux user, I am trying to setup mongodb on linux ubuntu 22.04 , I installed it using [mongdoDB official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) but it shows mongosh not working error
`mongosh command not found`
I have mongodb 6.0.5 version

I also had to uninstall and reinstall mongodb multiple times as it was showing

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

when i check the status by `sudo systemctl status mongod` command so I tried to find the solution, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72947001/14462948) . I also used `sudo rm /usr/bin/mongo*` command as suggested by the user and I think this is where the problem begins.
On runnig `mongosh` commmand it was showing

```
bash: /usr/bin/mongo: no such file or directory
```

after restarting my system now it is showing this

```
mongosh: command not found
```

I also tried installing [mongosh](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/install/#procedure) from its official documentary it is still not working and showing the same error
Do suggest some fixes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Comment: I already tried this and it says cannot install mongodb-server and mongodb-client , when I tried sudo upgrade only the above file it says files do not have installation instructions

Comment: Did you pay attention to this note: "*The mongodb package provided by Ubuntu is not maintained by MongoDB Inc. and conflicts with the official mongodb-org package. If you have already installed the mongodb package on your Ubuntu system, you must first uninstall the mongodb package before proceeding with these instructions.*"

Comment: Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit i actually ran ` sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org* ` this command many times when but now I ran ` sudo apt-get purge mongod-org* ` command thinking there might be some files with just mongod name and for some fortunate reason it is working perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I came accross the same issue.

From what I understood this is happening because in the MongoDB version 6.0 the shell does not come preinstalled, you need to install it separately [here](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell).
`mongo.exe` became `mongosh.exe`
You can add the `alias mongosh="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/6.0/bin/mongosh.exe"` to your `.bash_profile` and just type mongosh in your terminal to execute the shell.